# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 4) vs (None, 1)) in Tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a multi-label classification problem that I am trying to solve with Neural Network using Tensorflow 2.

The problem - I am trying to predict a `cause` and its corresponding `severity`. I can have `n` number of causes and each of the causes can have `m` possible severity.

Let's say for simplicity

- number of causes = 2
- number of each causes possible severity = 2
- So we essentially have 4 possible outputs
- We also have 4 possible input features

I wrote below code -

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

def get_model_multilabel(n_inputs, n_outputs):
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        #input layer
        Dense(10, input_dim=n_inputs, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'),
        ## two hidden layer
        Dense(10, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.2),
        Dense(5, kernel_initializer='he_uniform', activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.2),
        ## output layer
        Dense(n_outputs, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

n_inputs = 4 # because we have 4 features
n_outputs = 4 # because we have 4 labels

mlmodel = get_model_multilabel(n_inputs, n_outputs)

## train the model
mlmodel.fit(X_train,y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split = 0.2, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

`X_train.shape` is `(1144, 4)` and
`y_train.shape` is `(1144,)`

Note the `sigmoid` activation in the last layer and the `binary_crossentropy` loss function as I am trying to model a multi-label classification problem. Reference [How do I implement multilabel classification neural network with keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726518/how-do-i-implement-multilabel-classification-neural-network-with-keras)

When I train this, it throws error

`ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 4) vs (None, 1))`

Not sure what am I missing here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your Y_train is incorrect in shape it should be `(1144,n_outputs)` , instead it is `(1144,)` , which if reshaped is `(1144,1)` . Your code dosent know the number of samples so it becomes `(None,1)` . It must match with output shape or `(None,4)`. You have loaded the data incorrectly.